# Extremely slow MySql for even simplest queries

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to load a very simple data set with 1 million rows into MySQL table..

I load the data using LOAD DATA INFILE from 5-6 different files, which all contain same data in same structure, just for different days..

After loading the first 2 files, the load process began to take extremely slow, considering how small the files are (each file have apprximately 100MB with 100k rows)... It took more than 10 minutes to load a 100mb file!..

I thuoght the problem might be with the way I load the data and with my indexing, but I realised it was an overall problem with my MySQL.. For example, I ran the following query:

```
select count(*) from DataTable;
```

and it took MySQL 301 seconds to return the answer!!! (answer was 780 thousand)

I must be doing something very fundamentally wrong.. I checked the variables such as innodb buffer pool etc. but nothing looks out of ordinary...

I do realise Im asking a pretty fundamental question, but couldnt find any posts around complaining of a similarly fundamental issue..

Many thanks for the help..

---

Please find below the code I use for creating a the data table..

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`addata`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`addata` (
  `idAdData` INT NOT NULL,
  `Field1` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Field2` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field3` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field4` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field5` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field6` INT NULL,
  `Field8` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field9` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field10` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field11` INT NULL,
  `Field12` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field13` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field14` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Field15` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field16` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field17` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field18` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field19` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field20` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field21` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Field22` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `Field23` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Field24` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAdData`, `Field2`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Can you share the DDL that you use to create the table?

Comment: COUNT(*) is not necessarily the 'simplest query' for InnoDB -- without an index, you're going to incur a table scan, unlike MyISAM.

Comment: Thx... I have now updated my question with the DDL